# Missing something to get values from mysql using java in an Xpage

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I wrote a java class to get values from a Mysql db in an Xpage. The code is,

```
package com.vijay;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test {

    String name;
    String caty;
    float price;
    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public String test(){
        return "This is a class with just a single method";
    }

    public Test(){
    }

    public void db(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vijay","root","");
            st=con.createStatement();
            st.executeQuery("select * from prodet;");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.getMethod();
    }

    public void getMethod(){
            try {
                while(rs.next()){
                    name=rs.getString("name");
                    price=rs.getFloat("price");
                    caty = rs.getString("caty");                
                }
                con.close();
                st.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I put a label in the page and Computed its value with SSJS

```
var v = new com.vijay.Test();
v.db();
v.getMethod();
return v.name;
```

Even i put those two methods in the constructor too. But doesn't work.

Where do i miss?

Comment: Does your ResultSet contain any results? That is, does your rs.next() ever return true? Another thing, if you wrap your SSJS code into a try..catch block, do you get any error messages?

Comment: Ya it returned the statement which i gave in the catch block (in ssjs).

Comment: I did miss this pal: assigning the value st.execute() to the result set object.  It should be rs= st.execute(query);

Answer (score 0):

I think you must declare your field `name` as `public`.

```
public class Test {
   public String name;
```

Or much better, create a getter function:

```
public class Test {
   private String name;
   public String getName() {
     return name;
   }
```

And then change your SSJS code to `return v.getName()`.

By the way, there are two datasources in Extension Library (JDBCRowSet and JDBCQuery) which might be of interest to you.

Comment: It works fine without the Jdbc code but fails only when using the jdbc code. That's the one to be demystified.